# When is $\mathscr{T}_f=\mathscr{T}_c$ exactly?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, intuition

**BACKGROUND**

For any set $X$ and $\mathscr{T}$ a topology on $X$, $\mathscr{T}$ is finer than the [indiscrete (or trivial) topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) $\mathscr{T}_i$ on $X$.  The [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) $\mathscr{T}_d$ on $X$ is finer than $\mathscr{T}$.  That is, we have
$$\mathscr{T}_i \subseteq \mathscr{T} \subseteq \mathscr{T}_d.$$
We have the equality
$$\mathscr{T}_i = \mathscr{T} = \mathscr{T}_d$$
when the set $X = \emptyset$ or when $X$ is a singleton.

Similarly, the [cocountable topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) $\mathscr{T}_c$ is finer than the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) $\mathscr{T}_f$, or
$$\mathscr{T}_f \subseteq \mathscr{T}_c,$$
because every finite set is a countable set.

**PROBLEM**

When is $\mathscr{T}_f=\mathscr{T}_c$ exactly?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Equality occurs in 
$$\mathscr{T}_f \subseteq \mathscr{T}_c$$
when $X = \emptyset$ or when $X$ is finite, again because every finite set is a countable set, but not all countable sets are finite.

**QUESTION**

Is my intuition (as in my answer) correct?

Comment: When you say "$X$ consists of singletons", do you mean that $X$ is a singleton?

Comment: Yes, I meant to say that $X$ is a singleton @JohnGriffin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct!

> The cocountable and cofinite topologies on $X$ are equal iff $X$ is finite.

*Proof:*
If $X$ is infinite, then there is a countably infinite subset $D$ of $X$. (This uses the axiom of choice.) Then $D^c$ is cocountable, but not cofinite.
Conversely, if $X$ is finite, then every subset of $X$ is both cofinite and cocountable. This means that the cofinite, cocountable, and discrete topologies coincide.